# Digikam cannot play mp4 video in slideshow

Tags: kubuntu, video, digikam

With Kubuntu 15.04 and Digikam 4.13.0, Libkipi 2.2.0, videos can be viewed as preview (click in thumbnail), but not in a slideshow. During the slideshow, only a black screen is shown instead of the video.
But in e.g. vlc, mp4 videos in slideshow is no problem.
What is to do, to show mp4 vidoes in a slideshow with digikam?